# camera laser calibration package?

Tags: calibration, laser, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

is there any available package for calibrating the extrinsic parameters of camera + laser range finder system?

I found the old [laser_camera_calibration](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_camera_calibration) package, but I can't figure out where to find the source (roslocate does not return any result, and it is not in the browse list), and it does not seem to have been worked on since 2009.

Thanks in advance

Raph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10280/camera-laser-calibration-package?/) by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1382 on 2011-06-16

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can have a look at the paper of Vijay Pradeep on the calibration of the PR2. ([here](http://www.willowgarage.com/publications/author/207)). And in the source code of PR2.
Wim told me that there is an intern working on the extension on the camera pose calibration package, I proposed helping in extending this package to a more general 'multi sensor calibration' package.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5